# Dse is not starting stating unable to write to commit log directory

Tags: shell, cassandra

I am getting below error while starting the dse:
ERROR [main] 2020-02-26 13:08:33,269  DseModule.java:97 - {}. Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Unable to check disk space available to /u01/dse_ops/logs. Perhaps the Cassandra user does not have the necessary permissions
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to check disk space available to /u01/dse_ops/logs. Perhaps the Cassandra user does not have the necessary permissions

Comment: drwxr-xr--. 2 cassandra cassandra 6 Feb 26 13:07 logs

Comment: Please add additional information in your original post, as an edit, instead of as comments. Also try to be more precise in your problem statement and add more info. See [mcve].